# Pass Multiple Arguments with different data types : Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to pass 2 arguments of different data types using

```
Navigator.PushNamed(context, routeName, arguments)
```

How do I go about it?

For more context, I want to navigate from my Landing Page to my Sessions page by passing in two arguments of a different type, I tried the following way but it obviously didn't work.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: SessionType.signIn, Auth())
```

The `sessionsEnum.signIn` and `sessionsEnum.signUp` sets the SessionType in Sessions class to toggle sign in or sign up view. Whilst `Auth()` is an instance of my authentication class used to determine whether the user is signed in or out, and the UID. On init, the Session class would display view based on the arguments received; sign in or sign up.

What's the best way to implement this / work with passing two non-string arguments in Flutter's `Navigator.pushNamed()`?

Thanks.

For clarity, here's my Sessions class:

```
class Sessions extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'sessions';
  final BaseAuth baseAuth;
  SessionType sessionType;

  Sessions({this.baseAuth, this.sessionType});

  @override
  _SessionsState createState() => _SessionsState();
}

enum SessionType { signIn, signUp }

class _SessionsState extends State<Sessions> {
  //class wide declarations
  String email;
  String password;
  String error;

  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //validate form fields input and save
  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      print('form is valid, Email: $email, Password: $password');
      return true;
    } else {
      print('form is invalid');
      return false;
    }
  }

  String trimTextInput(String value) {
    return value.toString().trim();
  }

  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = true;
      });
      try {
        if (widget.sessionType == SessionType.signIn) {
          String user = await widget.baseAuth
              .handleSignIn(trimTextInput(email), trimTextInput(password));
          print('Signed in: $user');

          if (user == null) {
            setState(() {
              showSpinner = false;
              error = 'could not sign in with those credentials';
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              showSpinner = false;
            });
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, TakePayment.id);
          }
        } else {
          String user = await widget.baseAuth
              .handleSignUp(trimTextInput(email), trimTextInput(password));
          print('Signed up: $user');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: ${e.toString()}');
      }
    }
  }

  void toggleViewToSignUp() {
    _formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
      widget.sessionType = SessionType.signUp;
//      _sessionType = SessionType.signUp;
    });
  }

  void toggleViewToSignIn() {
    _formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
      widget.sessionType = SessionType.signIn;
//      _sessionType = SessionType.signIn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: buildInputFields() + submitButtons(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildInputFields() {
    return [
      TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onSaved: (value) => email = value,
        validator: EmailFieldValidator.validate,
        decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'enter your email'),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        validator: PasswordFieldValidator.validate,
        onSaved: (value) => password = value,
        decoration:
            kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'enter your password'),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> submitButtons() {
    if (widget.sessionType == SessionType.signIn) {
//    if (_sessionType == SessionType.signIn) {
      return [
        Buttons(
          buttonLabel: 'Sign In',
          buttonColour: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
          buttonTextStyle: kThemeStyleButton,
          onPressedButton: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        PaddedClickableText(
          myText: 'Don\'t have an account? Sign up now',
          onTap: toggleViewToSignUp,
        ),
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        Buttons(
          buttonLabel: 'Sign Up',
          buttonColour: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
          buttonTextStyle: kThemeStyleButton,
          onPressedButton: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        PaddedClickableText(
          myText: 'Already have an account? Sign in here',
          onTap: toggleViewToSignIn,
        ),
      ];
    }
  }
}

class EmailFieldValidator {
  static String validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null;
  }
}

class PasswordFieldValidator {
  static String validate(String value) {
    return value.length < 6 || value.isEmpty
        ? 'Password can\'t be empty'
        : null;
  }
}
```

This is the code from my Onboarding5 which uses the Navigator.pushNamed()...

```
class Onboarding5 extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'onboarding5';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'logo',
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                  child: Image.asset('images/logo_text.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            PaddingClass(
              bodyImage: 'images/start_here.png',
            ),
            Text(
              'Start here',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: kHeading1TextSize,
                color: kThemeTextColour,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            Buttons(
              onPressedButton: () {
//                Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id,
                    arguments: [SessionType.signUp, Auth()]);
              },
              buttonLabel: 'Sign Up',
              buttonColour: kWhiteButtonFillColour,
              buttonTextStyle: kWhiteButtonStyle,
            ),
            Buttons(
              onPressedButton: () {
//                Navigator.pushNamed(context, RootPage.id, arguments: Auth());
//                Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id,
                    arguments: [SessionType.signIn, Auth()]);
              },
              buttonLabel: 'Sign in',
              buttonColour: Colors.white,
              buttonTextStyle: kWhiteButtonStyle,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'We\'re social. Connect with us.',
                style: kRegularTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80.0, 10.0, 80.0, 10.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //TODO: Add an ontap listener to navigate to their respective social media pages when user clicks
                  Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.facebookSquare,
                    color: kThemeIconColour,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.twitterSquare,
                    color: kThemeIconColour,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.instagramSquare,
                    color: kThemeIconColour,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.linkedinIn,
                    color: kThemeIconColour,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: kThemeIconColour,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is an `Object` so you can pass any object to it. In your case you can pass both the argument as a list or you can pass them through a map of `Map<String, dynamic>` or you can even create another class which will hold these 2 objects. The choice is yours.

To pass them as a map.

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: {'session' : SessionsArgument(sessionEnum.signIn), 'auth' : Auth()});
```

To pass them as a list

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: [SessionsArgument(sessionEnum.signIn),Auth()]);
```

To pass them by creating a data Class.

```dart
Class ArgumentsClass {
  final SessionsArgument sessionArgument;
  final Auth auth;
  ArgumentsClass(this.sessionArgument,this.auth);
}

Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: ArgumentsClass(SessionsArgument(sessionEnum.signIn),Auth()));
```

To retrieve to arguments use ModalRoute settings.

```dart
List<dynamic> args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work.

I used Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: [SessionType.signIn, Auth()]); and Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: [SessionType.signUp, Auth()]); but it doesn't toggle. Only the sign up one works. well.

Comment: when I declare my SessionType as final in my Sessions Stateful class, it doesn't let me access the SessionType using widget.sessionType because of this error: lib/sign_in_up_screens/sessions.dart:93:14: Error: The setter 'sessionType' isn't defined for the class 'Sessions'.

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't toggle the right view after navigating to the SessionClass. I've edited my question above to display my entire SessionsClass

Comment: @hermie_brown add code of where you are calling the navigator.pushNamed with arguments also.

Comment: Done. Edited my question above to reflect my Onboarding5.dart

Comment: @hermie_brown Your code looks fine but I did not see any ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments to extract arguments in the session screen. Are you using onGenerateRoute to extract arguments and pass them in the constructor?

Comment: No I'm not using ModalRoute nor onGenerateRoute. Is that the missing link? How does that work?

Comment: @hermie_brown yes you were not extracting the arguments, I have updated my answer. Check the last code snippet and use that to retrieve the arguments which are passed.

Comment: Thanks. When I use it inside my Widget build(BuildContext context) {} I'm able to print out both arguments passed in using args[0] and args[1]. However, still sticking to my implementation above without creating a separate ArgumentsClass, how do I get each argument outside of the Widget build context? say I create a method to extract each argument. I am trying to simplify my code.

Comment: @hermie_brown afaik you can access those arguments anywhere using your class context. so the implementation depends on how you want to use them. You can mark the answer as accepted as the original question has been solved now.

Comment: @hermie_brown you can pass these arguments using constructors as well. You can read about onGenerate property of MaterialApp widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218913/discussion-between-hermie-brown-and-zeeshan-hussain).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions.id, arguments: [SessionsArgument(sessionEnum.signIn), Auth()])
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't toggle the right view after navigating to the SessionClass. I've edited my question above to display my entire SessionsClass